# C# SDK for non-IDE Java developer

Tags: c#, java, sdk

I've been playing with Java for years as a means of developing quick and easy tools for repetitive tasks.  I am not a true "developer" in the traditional sense, but I have lots of experience creating a wide assortment of tools and PoCs.

Unfortunately for me, I have noticed many shops are specifically looking for experience with C#, and not so many for Java.  Even here on SO, there are more questions and more followers to C# related issues than Java.  My preference will always be Java over C# simply for the cross-platform compatibility, but since the languages are so similar, I believe it would be beneficial for me to cross-train.  I have already dabbled in other languages and scripts (VB and other BASIC flavors, Javascript, VBScript, ASP, JSP, PHP, etc.) so adding another isn't out of the question.

My current Java environment simply consists of a text editor (primarily jEdit for its plugins and layout) and homemade scripts to compile/jar my projects.  I don't like to use IDEs because I want full control over my code and don't want a program writing code for me.  (I also prefer to write my own code as opposed to using any sort of external library/package, if feasible.  It helps me learn and greatly reduces unnecessary code.)

Therefore, what are my options for a non-IDE C# SDK?  Libraries are obviously not that important to me.  I've heard of Mono, which appears to separate the functions, but haven't tried it yet.  What other SDKs exist that are similar to a simple Java SDK combined with a text editor?

Comment: "I also prefer to write my own code as opposed to using any sort of external library/package, if feasible. It helps me learn and greatly reduces unnecessary code." The last bit sounds wrong to me - if you're writing code which someone else has already written, that's *introducing* unnecessary code.

Comment: No offense dude, but refusing an IDE because you want "full control and don't want a program writing code for me" is a bit silly. Embrace the tools that increase productivity. That's like saying "I refuse to use speed dial on my phone, I want full control over the phone numbers I dial."

Comment: @Jon: I understand what you mean, and have heard this argument before.  But since I am not writing traditional full-fledged applications, and my code is likely not going to be reused (that may change), it simplifies the code I am writing, decreases file size, and potentially increases speed/responsiveness.  If I were to be collaborating with others as most shops do, I can clearly see the benefit of an IDE.

Comment: @D.N. Is file size actually a problem for you? Do you have any evidence that using libraries reduces speed/responsiveness? Why would avoiding a well-designed API which someone else has laboured on *simplify* your code? Do you plan to write your own XML parser, HTTP library etc in order to avoid the ones in the framework?

Comment: @BFree: I guess my environment has never been one where pure development productivity is not important (mostly because that was never my primary role).  If that situation were to change, I'd embrace an IDE as needed.  But if nothing else, I want to learn the code well before I use an IDE.

Comment: @D.N.: Using an IDE will *help* you understand the code quicker - by giving you warnings as you type, encouraging appropriate formatting, making it easier to navigate around your code etc.

Comment: @Jon: Perhaps this isn't the best example, but my philosophy is similar to implementing an interface than using a pre-made class.  The class will have more logic, more initialization, etc. that I may know for certain I will not need.  Maybe I should only concern myself with this if speed/responsiveness truly is an issue, but I guess I'm a "purist" of sorts...

Comment: @D.N.: Maybe you won't need all the features of C# either. Better design your own language too. Maybe you won't need all the features of your OS... time to throw away Windows/Linux/whatever. Do you actually use all the instructions within your CPU? Time to break out the silicon... In short, your approach simply isn't pragmatic in my view. Learning to evaluate and use libraries effectively is an important skill - why would you want to ignore it?

Comment: @Jon: Point taken.  I'll need to wrap my head around the idea of throwing away my philosophy I've held for so long.  I guess I've oft confused an IDE with a "designer" as you state in your answer.  I still learn my errors via the compiler, and in my defense I believe that having to wait that long reinforces good coding techniques, but can see the benefit of a real-time assistant for API syntax.

Comment: ...and I'm gonna go ahead and +1 your comment for actually spurring me into downloading Eclipse for my Java development.  I'm going to simmer on the jump to C# before I select any answers :)  I am a little overwhelmed by the amount of traction this answer got, but I guess I shouldn't be surprised with the tags I used.  This community is very supportive.

Comment: Visual Studio is, honestly, a joy to use! It will make your life easier :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using an IDE doesn't have to mean anything writing code for you. I'm not generally keen on designer-generated code, but unless you decide to *use* a designer (or snippets etc), Visual Studio won't be writing code for you. Of course it will create a skeleton class for you when you create one, add the appropriate method signatures when you implement an interface etc - but is that boilerplate *really* something you want to write yourself?

I'd also suggest that your policy of not using external libraries is a bad one. I agree that it's useful for educational purposes to sometimes reimplement something, but it means that the code quality is likely to end up being worse... why would you not want to use code that has already been used and improved by many other people? Yes, you need to be careful about what libraries you use - but you really don't want to do *everything* yourself... not if you want to be productive, anyway.

I often use a text editor and command line myself for simple test code (e.g. for Stack Overflow questions) but I wouldn't dream of doing that for "real" code that I plan to keep.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it touches on the most relevant points of all answers, not just because it's Jon Skeet. :) I'm not a developer by profession, nor do I care to be. My projects are little tools or for learning. I've not needed to use libraries for anything except some .XLS reading/writing, but have easily worked around that with CSV on other projects. Eclipse seems like an 800lb gorilla, and I had almost all of the features it offers as plugins in jEdit. However, I do see the importance of an IDE and using libraries, so I will remain open in the future. Thanks for changing my mind!

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, a lot of C# and .NET is about learning the tools; Visual Studio gives you a lot that you wouldn't be able to do with a text editor. There's a free version, and I highly suggest you check it out! People hiring will want to know that you're familiar with the tools they'll most likely be using.

Comment: Intellisense == Hmm, I don't remembering seeing that class but it looks interesting.... [sometime later after googling it]. Time to remove that code, the Framework does it for me.

Comment: I agree with Andy.  The reason C# developers are sought is usually because they have skills in the surrounding tools.  Without an IDE it is going to be very time consuming for you to deal with source control, automated tests, refactoring, and perform Linq queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can just start with Notepad and csc.exe, the the command-line C# compiler that ships with the .NET SDK.

However, IDE is not necessarily synonym for code generator. I would download Visual Studio Express and start with empty Console projects.

Have fun!

Comment: +1 for answering the question, though I don't think anyone else agrees with the question submitter.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda get that feeling too.  Perhaps it's for the best that nobody does :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget you can build/assemble C# projects using [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) and a .sln file if you really want. But the IDEs will make life a *lot* easier.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE will not write code for you, it will help you writing code. Using libraries will help you concentrate on what you really want to program, not the things that already have been done.

Answer (score 0):

Check into AvalonEdit, the text editor component of SharpDevelop.  It is an open source text editor that has classes that could implement features such as intellisense and syntax highlighting.  You would only have to use as much of it as you wanted and you could embed it anywhere you would use a text box control.

If you are familiar with Ant from Java then you could also check out NAnt to do your compile phase.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, with Visual Studio you also get a command line C# compiler, `csc`. You could use a text editor and manually compile your C# code with that on the command line if you really want - that wouldn't be very practical however when your project contains more than a handful of source files.

If your project becomes bigger, you could use a tool like [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/), which is a .NET version of the popular Java build tool [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/).

I agree with Jon Skeet about that your way of working is not very practical. If you are really looking for a software development job, you'd better learn to use the tools that other developers use. An employer will also not accept the fact that you'd want to write all the code yourself instead of using libraries. By using libraries instead of writing it all yourself you save lots of time, you are reusing well-tested code and your code will be much easier to maintain by other developers.